# Real time frame grabbing from video through webcam on google colab

Tags: python, opencv, frame, webcam, google-colaboratory

I have created a very basic image classification model using keras trained on the CIFAR-10 dataset. I extended its basic functionality to predict on user provided data. Now I want to move to real-time classification.
This requires me to integrate my webcam with my notebook and use frame grabbing techniques to classify the images. 
I referred a code for doing just that. But the code constantly throws this error and I am not sure what I am supposed to do

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import random
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
i=0
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(frame)
    i+=1
    cv2.imwrite('database/{index}.png'.format(index=i),frame)
    cv2_imshow(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        15 
>        16 
>   ---> 17     cv2_imshow(frame)
>        18     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
>        19         break
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/patches/**init**.py
>   in cv2_imshow(a)
>        20       image.
>        21   """
>   ---> 22   a = a.clip(0, 255).astype('uint8')
>        23   # cv2 stores colors as BGR; convert to RGB
>        24   if a.ndim == 3:
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clip'

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience but I don't think this solves my problem exactly. The error is in the part where I call the cv2_imshow patch that google wants me to use rather than the cv2.imshow to display the frame captured continually. If you still think that the mentioned link solves my problem please do elaborate how.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but `cv2.imshow` will not work in Google Colab since it is a server based system. So you have to use a snippet of code which is provided in google colab left side section but I don't know how to extract frames from that code.

Answer (score 0):

Google colab is running on server so for accessing webcam through google colab you have to use JavaScript function and which is given in file:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb